# Jquery function to find out max height of <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find out that out of the given `<li>` which `li` has the maximum height?
how do i write such function?

If there are n `<li>` elements of different size, content and height. I want to figure out the maximum height of the biggest `<li>` element.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
var max = -1;
$("li").each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height(); 
    max = h > max ? h : max;
});
alert(max);
```

Comment: Alternatively `max = Math.max(max, $(this).height());`, should anyone (besides me) find this more readable.

Comment: @jensgram, +1, forgot about this

Comment: This has always worked very well for me, BUT, I recently used it for divs that had a float attribute. This created a very odd bug. Even more curious was the fact that the bug would only show up depending on the type of text structure (single lines vs paragraphs) that appeared in the floated div. In any case, removing the float, then running the above, and then reapplying the float afterward using another line of jQuery did the trick. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 20):

If you want a one liner

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $("li").map(function() { return $(this).height(); }))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var liMaxHeight = -1;
var node;
$("li").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > liMaxHeight) {
        liMaxHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        node = index;
    }
});
alert("li with index " + node + " has height " + liMaxHeight);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QUycm/

[`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) includes padding and border. If don't want to include padding and border use [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to get all the `<li>` elements, and do a manual loop to compare them against each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = -1 , current = null ;
var li = null ;

$("li").each(  function(i,node) {
    if(  ( current = $(this).height( ) ) > max ) max = current , li = node ;
}  ) ;
```

That will give you the node and its height at one swoop

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution.

We are going to loop through the elements and find the one with the highest height.

We can make use of jquery to easily do this.

- we will create an empty array.
- Loop through our elements and store all the heights in this array
- Then find the max height in that array
- We will loop through again and set all our elements to that maximum height.

  ```
   var heights = [];
          $('.your-class-name').each(function () {
              heights.push($(this).height());
          });
          var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
          $('.your-class-name').each(function () {
              $(this).height(maxHeight);
          });
  ```

Kaboom.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.equalHeightPlugin = function () {
                        var self = this;
                        return {
                            getMaxHeight: function () {
                                let max = 0;
                                self.each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).height() > max) max = $(this).height();    
                                })
                                return max;
                            },
                            setMaxHeight: function (botOffset) {
                                let _offSet_ = 0;
                                _offSet_ = (typeof arguments[0] === "undefined") ? 0 : botOffset;                                  
                                self.height(this.getMaxHeight() + _offSet_);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

You can use the above plugin to make all chosen selectors the same height.

to call the plugin if you want to set maximum height for all selectors:

```
var selector = $(".your-selector").equalHeightPlugin();
selector.setMaxHeight(offset);//you can have some pixels to adjust your height
```

If you want to get the maximum height, you can simply do this:

```
selector.getMaxHeight();
```